# Swift 2.1 - Clear textfield in TableViewCell after cell is deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

I have a TableView for adding recipe instructions(steps). First cell is given and user can add more cells as they need it.
And user can delete a cell they don't need.

Each cell(row) is configured with a UITextfield for instruction text content and a UILabel for labelling the instruction order.

One of the possible use case may be that user has typed some text in a cell and decides to delete it to start over. When user presses **add step** button, user will be presented with a new cell but with previous text filled in.
To prevent this, I have `cell.stepTextField.text = ""` so user can get a cell with a clear textfield.

It kind of works but when I play around with many possible interactions, I get funny result like the attached screenshot. In that example screenshot, I lost the instruction in the first cell even though I did not delete this cell.

How do I make sure user will get a clean textfield every time and not lose text of other cells?

I've tried `cell.stepTextField.removeFromSuperview()` also but this will completely remove a textfield of a cell which is not what I want.

Please note that I'm not doing any update on DataSource in delete function as I get values of all textfields of the tableview in the **Save** function only.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if tableView == stepTableView {

        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            if stepOrder.count > 1 {

                let cell = self.stepTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! StepCell?
                cell!.stepTextField.text = ""
                stepTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }

        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }

    }

}
```

(Update)
**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.stepTableView {
        let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StepCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StepCell
        stepTextField = aCell.getTextField()
        aCell.configureStepOrder(stepOrder[indexPath.row])
        aCell.stepTextField.delegate = self
        cell = aCell
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: add tag to textfield in cellforRowAtIndex method and then you can clear particular textfiled text value while deleting cell

Comment: can you share the code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: @SeongLee you are getting strange results because you are reusing cells and are not saving the changes made by the user...

Comment: @vivektakrani Would you mind elaborating it? I've only seen examples that reuses cells and what I'm trying to achieve is kind of unique so some guideline will be useful.

Comment: you need to have some way of storing the data of tableviews/collectionviews. This can be an array of strings in your case. cellForRowAtIndexPath would then take the text from the array through `array[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` (or just `[indexPath.row]` if you don't use sections)

Comment: This is necessary because cells in tableviews/collectionviews are reused, practically this means that a cell disappearing from view will be dequeued and reused as a cell that is appearing while scrolling. So they don't have a fixed order on their own. A separate array that holds the data would have a fixed order.

Comment: Thanks @RMenke but same question to you: I've tried storing the changes in an array but it's not clear when to save it. 
I can save each textfield text when user presses "return" on the keyboard or when they click `add step` but user can just dismiss the keyboard without pressing any of them. Should I save the change when the user does endEditing, too?

Comment: I cover all needed delegate calls. If you need to register `return` and `endEditing`, you should. Another way is to monitor all text changes.

Comment: @RMenke How can I use indexPath.row in UITextField delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array to store all the changes made by the user...
where the index will be your cell number

```
var textFieldArray = [String]()
```

Now when user clicks on Add step append an empty string in textFieldArray

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath add this

```
cell.stepTextField.text = textFieldArray[indexPath.row]
cell.stepTextField.tag = indexPath.row
```

Now when user deletes the cell remove that element from textFieldArray and reload the tableView

```
textFieldArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
tableView.reload()
```

Comment: I've tried storing the changes in an array but it's not clear when to save it. 
I can save each textfield text when user presses "return" on the keyboard or when they click `add step` but user can just dismiss the keyboard without pressing any of them. Should I save the change when the user does endEditing, too?

Comment: Ok. In that case, I believe that should be the only one taking care of saving.

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` when the `Type` is known. Just use `[String]`

Comment: Before with this approach, I was stuck in which index of array I should update the value. I first populate array with "" so I won't get index out of range error with table cell configuration and I need to update that empty value. User can jump to the first cell without pressing any button while editing 3rd cell for example.

Comment: I guess textFieldDidChange method will solve this issue but how do I use the indexPath.row in textfield delegate method?

Comment: And why is tag necessary here?

Comment: I used this tag in the textfield delegate method as an indexPath.row. This is now working as it should. Thanks!

Comment: Glad @RMenke and I could help..:)

Answer (score 0):

The safest way you can do what you want is

1. Use a temporary array for the data source. Create a copy of the saved array when you show the table view.
2. Always synchronize the changes you make to the table view with the temporary data source (insert, edit, delete). You can have an empty string in the array for the empty cell.
3. If you want to save the changes, just copy the temporary array to the saved one. A simple assignment will do.

As for the text changes, make sure you implement the needed delegate methods.

I hope this helps!